# Flutter item adding and removing (chips)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to **add and remove items(Chips)** when clicked, this is my code

```
  var _chipsList = <Widget>[];
```

calling this each time I needed to add a chip to `_chipsList`:

```
 _addChip(text, fontSIZO) {
    _chipsList = List.from(_chipsList)
      ..add(Wrap(
        key: ObjectKey(text),  // I think here is my problem
        children: <Widget>[
            Chip(
              label: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: fontSIZO * .8,
                ),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              onDeleted: () {
                _chipsList = List.from(_chipsList)..remove(text);
                setState(
                  () {},
                );
              },
            ),
          
        ],
      ));
    setState(() {});
  }
```

in widget build:

```
  Wrap(
    children: _chipsList,
  ),
```

Adding works fine but I have problem removing the chips I need to use **ObjectKey** because I have similar lists in the same page but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Note:I think this code is enough but please tell me if u need extra info of the code.

Comment: Can you show the ```ListView.builder``` or ```ListView```?

Comment: I did not use a ListView.builder or ListView

Comment: @pskink yeah it works fine thank u for your code but I was hoping to get an answer using ObjectKey

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better approach to maintain data and the widget separately.

```dart
List<String> _chipList = [];

// use state to add/remove from list

setState((){
  _chipList.add('item');
});

setState((){
  _chipList.remove('item');
})
```

In the `build()` method you can then write the code for the UI using `List.generate()`

```dart
Wrap(
  children: List.generate(
    _chipList.length,
    (int index) => Chip(
      // rest of your code // use _chipList[index] to access values
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you change key value?

```
 key: UniqueKey()
```

Comment: I tried this before and it did not work, I still can't delete the item